# Getting data from pubsubMessage in Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

From a node.js server I'm trying to send data to a Pub/Sub topic and then fire a Cloud Function once it triggers.

I'm succesfully sending messages to Pub/Sub, however when I try to interpret the data in the function I get the error "No telemetry data was provided" - see function bellow.

I'm following this: https://github.com/GabeWeiss/GoogleIoTCoreApp/tree/master/gcf/telemetryToFirestore

Here's how I call it (this works):

```js
const pubsub = new PubSub();
const topicName = 'topixXx';    
const dataJ = JSON.stringify([{"temperature": 1}, {"bpm": 2}]); 
const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(dataJ);
const messageId = pubsub.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);      
res.end(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
```

And here's the CGF (I've cut part of the function, i'ts not needed for the case):

```
const admin = "...";
admin.initializeApp();
var db = "..";

exports.telemetryToFirestore = (event, callback) => {
const pubsubMessage = event.data;
throw new Error("pubsubMessage.data: "+pubsubMessage.data);
    if (!pubsubMessage.data) {
         throw new Error('No telemetry data was provided!');
     }
const payload = Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString();
const telemetry = JSON.parse(payload);


db.collection(......)
callback(.....);
};
```

Comment: I think you have a simple error here.

The passed in "event" object contains a field called "data" that is the data of the pubsub message.  You are then setting "pubsubMessage" to be the data.  And THEN you are asking for a field called "data" within pubsubMessage.  I think you may have a mistake in and trying to double dereference "data"